# How to test comparison if input will be truncated?

Tags: c, integer, comparison

So I have something cast as an int, and from my understanding maximum value for an int is 32676, and any value above this will be truncated in C.

If my program has the user inputting data, how can I check if this data can be fully stored in an int, because if it is not I need to tell the user to reinput the data.

For example, if the user tries to put in 450000, I need to tell them to re-input the data, however, a simple comparison seems to truncate the value first before comparing it to INT_MAX?

Comment: read it into a double :) then do the comparision

Comment: While that would work for the int case, I also have a situation where I'm reading in an unsigned long, and I can't do the same for that can I?

Comment: i think my answer would help

Comment: Added some code for explanation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Better Approach is as Follows

Scan the number as a String and then convert INT_MAX to String. Use `itoa()` for this.

Make a string comparison and then accordingly print a message. You will not have the problem to store it in any int or float or anything.

**EDIT:Added a working code**

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main(){
char lhs[200];
printf("enter the number");
scanf("%s",lhs); 
char rhs[200];
sprintf(rhs, "%d", 2147483647);
int rc = strcmp(lhs, rhs);
if(rc == 0)
    printf("[%s] equals [%s]\n", lhs, rhs);
else if(rc < 0)
    printf("[%s] more than [%s]\n", lhs, rhs);
else if(rc > 0)
    printf("[%s] less than [%s]\n", lhs, rhs);
return 0 ;
}
```

Comment: Nice. But it would be better if you use `INT_MAX` as the third argument of `sprintf`. Also, use `%199s` instead of `%s` in the `scanf` in order to prevent buffer overflows.

Comment: First, I believe you have swapped the conditions here, rc > 0 means that lhs is greater than rhs. And second, and most importantly, string comparison is substantially different from number comparison, e.g. "9" > "2147483647" because the first character, "9" is bigger than "2".

Answer (score 1):

I recommend storing the data in a type which allows larger values, like a `long` or a `double` depending on the data you are entering and then checking against `INT_MAX` before casting down.

A full list of the type limit can be found [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/limits_h.htm).